# getLastRow() not respecting data input on row 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where it has a header on row 1. When I use `getLastRow()` it takes the cells which already has a value which is my header.

```
const referralFormLinkDRH = targetSheet1.getRange(targetSheet1.getLastRow(), 15, 1, 1)
```

I used the one above first and it was working yesterday, but suddenly today for some weird reason it doesn't work anymore so I opted to use another one which is the one below.

```
const referralFormLinkDRH = targetSheet1.getRange(targetSheet1.getDataRange().getValues().length, 15, 1, 1)
```

It still didn't work and I really don't know what is happening. I use this kind of method because I am currently holding multiple sheets at a time. Was there an update that I was not aware of or is there something wrong with the script?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from `but suddenly today for some weird reason it doesn't work anymore`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wish to do something like this:

```
function lfunck(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//target sheet
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```